# Não está inserindo dados no BD MyPhpAdmin localhost

Tags: php, banco-de-dados, phpmyadmin, tabela-banco-de-dados, localhost

Olá. Estou realizando um exemplo passo a passo de um mini curso pelo YouTube.

Fiz a tela de setup em php com framework PHP: nome, email, senha, clico em Salvar dados e a validação funciona corretamente. Validação seria printar a mensagem de alerta se a pessoa não está digitando correntamente.

Deu validação ok e na hora de verificar lá no BD (localhost) se deu tudo certo, não tem nenhum registro.

Poderia me ajudar?

Banco: localhost
username: root
Sem senha
database: cursoci

Tabela: options
colunas: id (int:11)PK, option_name (varchar:255) e option_value (text)

Controller: setup.php

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Setup extends CI_Controller {

function __construct(){
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->helper('form');
    $this->load->library('form_validation');
    $this->load->model('option_model', 'option'); 
}

public function index(){
    
    if($this->option->get_option('setup_executado') == 1):
        // setup ok, mostrar tela para editar dados de setup
        redirect('setup/alterar','refresh');
    else:
        //não instalado, mostra tela de setup
        redirect('setup/instalar','refresh');
    endif;
}

public function instalar(){
    //O começo é igual a função index
    if($this->option->get_option('setup_executado')==1): 
        redirect('setup/alterar','refresh'); 
    endif;

    // regras de validação
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('login', 'NOME', 'trim|required|min_length[5]');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'EMAIL', 'trim|required|valid_email');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('senha', 'SENHA', 'trim|required|min_length[6]');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('senha2', 'REPITA A SENHA', 'trim|required|min_length[6]|matches[senha]'); 

    //verifica a validação
    if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE):
        if(validation_errors()):
            set_msg(validation_errors()); 
        endif;
    else:
        set_msg('<p>validação okk</php>');
    endif;
    //carrega view
    $dados['titulo'] = 'RBernardi - Setup do Sistema';
    $dados['h2'] = 'Setup do Sistema';
    $this->load->view('painel/setup', $dados);
}
}
```

View: painel/setup.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<title> <?php echo $titulo; ?></title>  <!–  DEU CERTO O TÍTULO ->
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,100,300,500,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url('assets/css/estilo.css') ?>" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url('assets/css/painel.css') ?>" />
</head>
<body>
<div class="linha">
    <div class="coluna col3">&nbsp;</div> 
    <div class="coluna col6">
        <h2><?php echo $h2; ?></h2> 
        <?php
            if($msg = get_msg()): 
               echo '<div class="msg-box">'.$msg.'</div>';
            endif;
            echo form_open();
            echo form_label('Nome para login:', 'login'); 
            echo form_input('login', set_value('login'), array('autofocus' => 'autofocus')); 
            echo form_label('Email do Administrador do site:', 'email');
            echo form_input('email', set_value('email'));
            echo form_label('Senha:', 'senha');
            echo form_password('senha', set_value('senha'));
            echo form_label('Repita a Senha:', 'senha2');
            echo form_password('senha2', set_value('senha2'));
            echo form_submit('envia', 'Salvar dados', array('class' => 'botao')); 
            echo form_close();
        ?>
    </div>
    <div class="coluna col3">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
```

Model: option_model.php

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Option_model extends CI_Model {

function __construct(){
    parent::__construct();
}

public function get_option($option_name){
    $this->db->where('option_name', $option_name);
    $query = $this->db->get('options', 1);
    if($query->num_rows() == 1):
        $row = $query->row();
        return $row->option_value;
    else:
        return NULL;
    endif;
}
```

Helper: funcoes_helper.php

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

if(!function_exists('set_msg')): 
function set_msg($msg=NULL){ 
    $ci = & get_instance(); 
    $ci->session->set_userdata('aviso', $msg); 
}
endif;

if(!function_exists('get_msg')):
function get_msg($destroy=TRUE){ 
    $ci = & get_instance();
    $retorno = $ci->session->userdata('aviso'); 
    if($destroy) $ci->session->unset_userdata('aviso'); 
    return $retorno; 
}
endif;
```

routes.php

```
$route['login'] = 'setup/login';
$route['painel'] = 'setup/login';
```

autoload.php

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('database', 'session');
$autoload['helper'] = array('url', 'funcoes');
```

assets/css/painel.css

```
label{
display: block;
font-size: 13px;
font-weight: 300;
}
input, textarea{
display: block;
margin-bottom: 15px;
padding: 5px 2%;
width: 96%;
}
input[type="file"]{
padding-left: 0;
}
textarea{
height: 150px;
}
input.botao{
width: auto;
}
.msg-box{
background: #f1f2ea;
border: 1px solid #c7cbab;
padding: 5px 10px;
margin-bottom: 15px;
color: #727272;
}

.msg-box p{
margin: 0;
padding: 2px 0;
}
```

Comment: Poderia incluir um MCVE. Para saber mais leia o guia para entender como [funciona a cumunidade](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8045/103217)

Comment: Importante você [edit] sua pergunta e explicar de maneira objetiva e pontual a dificuldade encontrada, trocando o código por um [mcve] do problema. Para entender que tipo de pergunta serve para o site e, consequentemente, evitar fechamentos e negativações vale a pena ler [O que é o Stack Overflow](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7256/70) e o [Guia de sobrevivência (resumido) do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8089/70).

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Não conheço o framework mas em nenhum momento do código vc mostrou algo que altera dados do banco. Acredito que seu curso ainda não tenha feito a função de insert.

Achei seu curso na web e foi isso mesmo. Faltou  a lógica de inserção.

```
}else{
            //set_msg('<p>validação ok</p>');
            $dados_form = $this->input->post();
            $this->option->update_option('user_login',$dados_form['login']);
            $this->option->update_option('user_email',$dados_form['email']);
            $this->option->update_option('user_pass',password_hash($dados_form['senha'],PASSWORD_DEFAULT));
            
            $inserido = $this->option->update_option('setup_executado',1);
            if($inserido){
                set_msg('<p>Sistema INSTALADO</p>');
                redirect('setup/login','refresh');
            }

        }
```

Comment: Mas antes de eu chegar nessa parte, estava inserindo normalmente.

Comment: Olha a lógica do seu controller. Só mostra a msg mesmo . Nao tem nada mais no seu código ' set_msg('<p>validação okk</php>'); '

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UyQSPdIPrSc&list=PLInBAd9OZCzz2vtRFDwum0OyUmJg8UqDV&index=8

Comment: 13:14 do video aí, ele cadastra e valida, só que ele não verifica no bd se cadastrou, ai que fico na dúvida, se foi cadastrado no bd nessa hora, depois disso ele faz alguns códigos e cadastra novamente e dá certo.

Comment: Minuto 21. Ele esta colocando o que falta no seu controller, No minuto 13 não existe salvamento na base. Existe é apenas consulta na base feita na função  get_option

Comment: Fiz até o minuto 23.34 e deu um erro: An uncaught Exception was encountered
Type: Error
Message: Call to undefined method Option_model::update_option()

Comment: update_option()  está faltando ser criado então. está no minuto 14. Estou até aprendendo codignition. Achei legal.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135997/discussion-between-andre-and-leo-chaves).